# Transparent image displays with black background

Tags: android, picasso

Downloading an image from server using Picasso library, it displays black. Because that is a QR code image with transparent background. it is working in some devices but not working in nexus 6 - version 5.0. Please help me to solve the issue.

```
 Picasso.with(this).load(url).into(imageview, new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "image loaded successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onError() {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error Loading Image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Xml :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="90dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="90dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="164dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) demonstrating your problem. In this case, that would include the source code (including the layout) where you are using this image, plus a link to an image that gives you this behavior.

Comment: please check the  code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is working fine in Glide library. The problem is in Picasso.